# Is there any WORKING CSS method to print page counting?

Tags: html, css, printing, pagination

I've searching for any solution to print page counting with CSS, but every "solution" found does not work in any browser, no valid solutions, only tips.

Aparently,

```
@page {
    @bottom-left {
        content: "blablabla"
    }
}
```

Is a valid CSS3 rule, but is not working in any browser.

Can someone please help-me?

This is a NOT WORKING example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test example</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            @bottom-left {
                counter-increment: page;
                content: counter(page);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
         <!-- LONG CONTENT HERE -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I faced the same problem. Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no! :(

Comment: yeah, I've found it already. It appears that none of major browser supports these margin boxes - [margin boxes support comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Grammar_and_rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@page { @bottom {} }` is NOT valid CSS3.

You have the following [available to you](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#painting):

```
@bottom-right-corner
@bottom-right
@bottom-center
@bottom-left
@bottom-left-corner
```

Comment: Sorry, i Thinked `@bottom-left` and wrote `@bottom`.

Even in simplest HTML example I could not make it work!